# OC4j to Weblogic migration issue with connection manager

Tags: java, oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, oc4j

I am trying to migrate java project from oc4j to weblogic. So I created xml files related to weblogic and able to load ear and ejb beans in weblogic.

But in my project few modules are connecting to database with below code.

```
ApplicationModule am = null;
ViewObjectImpl view = null;
Object[] retArray = null;
try {
    am = ConnectionManager.getInstance().check_out_bc4j(biz); // this line throws error
    view = (ViewObjectImpl)am.findViewObject(strViewObjName);
    if (sql != null) {
        view.setQuery(sql);
    }
```

`ConnectionManager.getInstance().check_out_bc4j(biz)` :This line threw
 below error in weblogic.

**Error:**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   oracle/jbo/JboContext

So I added these jars:  **antlr,adfm,bc4jmt,mdsrt,xml,concurrent.**

After added above jars I am getting below error.

> **Error**
>  Oracle.jbo.PersistenceException: JBO-26000: A
>   Generic exception occurred during loading Customizations.
>                   at oracle.jbo.mom.MOMParserNonMDS.parse(MOMParserNonMDS.java:190)
>
> oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory findOrCreateADFConfig INFO:
>   oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory No META-INF/adf-config.xml
>   found

so I added `config.xml` I am getting other error.

> **Error:**
>  Apr 24, 2019 4:47:43 PM
>   oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory findOrCreateADFConfig INFO:
>   oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigFactory Reading
>   META-INF/adf-config.xml Apr 24, 2019 4:47:43 PM
>   oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl getResultFromComponent
>   INTERNAL_ERROR: oracle.adf.share.config.ADFConfigImpl  null
>   java.lang.ClassCircularityError:
>   oracle/mds/config/MDSConfigurationException
>                   at oracle.adf.share.config.ADFMDSConfig.parseADFConfiguration(ADFMDSConfig.java:125)

Please anybody can help on this.

Comment: Have you actually installed the ADF Runtime Libs into your 12c as per https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/weblogic-12c-adf-application-development-runtime-installation-on-oracle-linux ? or something similar for your Weblogic Installation ? I would not be adding any extra .jars, install the runtime as per Oracle instructions and then try..

Comment: Hi Mkane, I did convert this calls to normal jpa calls..